# Set composite primary key

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to create a database-table using composite primary key in `Java Apache MetaModel`.

I am creating database-table using below code :

```
org.eobjects.metamodel.create.TableCreationBuilder tableCreator;
//Getting TableCreater object from schema and table name.
tableCreator.withColumn("id").asPrimaryKey();
tableCreator.withColumn("name");
tableCreator.withColumn("address");
tableCreator.withColumn("phone");
java.io.Serializable.Table table = tableCreator.execute()
```

It is working fine for me. and set "id" as primary key. But I want to set composite primary key "id and name"
How can I do this?

Comment: What technique/tool are you using?

Comment: @Ronak I would need to be able to see the `org.eobjects.metamodel.create.TableCreationBuilder` API to be able to comment on it.  However, the old fashioned way would be to generate a creation statement which specifies a composite key as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp), and execute the create statement as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/tables.html#create)

Comment: @Alan google is your friend: http://metamodel.apache.org/

Comment: @JimAho Java Apache MetaModel technique

Comment: @Ronak The reason I asked was because I thought it would be easier for other people to help you if you included it in the question :)

Comment: @JimAho I added it in question

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks! Google wasn't my friend when I googled it before though.  I must have had the wrong keywords, or been in a bad google bubble.

Comment: I removed the tag [tag:apache] as that is specifically for Apache HTTP server.